# Open "Questions with similar titles"  suggested Question in new tab, onclick?

Tags: support, questions, user-interface, usability

When a user try to ask a question he/she will see an option like:

**Questions with similar titles**

If the user clicks on any suggested link, it's opening in the *same window* (at present).

For better user friendly nature, if we have an option to open in new tab/window, 
that will help user to see the question, without loosing any data he entered after clicking on suggested link on StackExchange.

An alternative way is, keep the `session` by placing `back button` **or** after user clicks on `back` icon on browser.

**Note:** this Question was based on the Functional and Beginner/intermediate (technical) people who use Stack Exchange as a good source of finding right knowledge.
[image]

Comment: As opposed to being in control and letting the user decide this, via the right-click or mouse?

Comment: @random question isn't referring any control, it's only for user friendly nature.

Comment: @random: Wouldn't adding `target="_blank"` just change the *default* behavior to a new tab/window (depending on preferences) and still allow the user to open in the same tab/window if they really want too. I think it makes more sense to use a new window so that the user still has their content (and the list of similar questions) to go back too when they close the new tab/window.

Comment: Perhaps the similar titles could also [blink](http://www.sightspecific.com/~mosh/WWW_FAQ/blink.html), to aid in further usability.

Comment: As a note i mentioned, it will help beginners to work on this StackExchange, without any problem while submitting a new question. I thought it will help.(it's not for stupendous guys).

Comment: Making the behavior of the web inconsistent does *not* help beginners: *consistent behavior* helps beginners and experts alike. Don't mess with the semantics of my links.

Comment: @dmckee What do you mean by **inconsistent** here!, for links stackexchange fallowing principles like `<a href="question..." target="_self">(default) or target="_parent"`. you can _answer_ the question with proper details.

Answer (score 6):

I *detest* websites that think they know how my windows should be managed.

If I want content open in a new window, I'll open it myself.

Comment: +1, but out of curiosity, are you ok with gmail assuming you want links from emails opened in a new window?

Comment: @Adam: Good point. I _moderately dislike_ that behavior on Gmail. (What I _detest_ in Gmail is how difficult it is to get the Gmail interface to show me the content in a fixed-width font; the "Show Original" feature brings up a new window, and I _always_ hit the `H` "back" key on my keyboard after reading only to find that _it does nothing because "show original" opened a new window_.)